# Writing an XML using XmlSerializer and Change prefix N0 to NS1

Tags: android, xml, xml-serialization

I am using XML

I am trying to set the prefix to NS1 throught the whole document, so i used :

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.setPrefix("ns1", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");
        serializer.setPrefix("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        serializer.startTag("ns1" , "HBA");

        serializer.startTag("ns1", "TITLE");
        serializer.text(cd.title);
        serializer.endTag("ns1", "TITLE");
        // and till the end
```

but when i check the XML file i see this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><n0:HBA xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n0="ns1"><n0:TITLE></n0:TITLE>
```

so here as you can see the prefix is set to N0 not NS1 as i require. also the XML is writen side ways, but i would like to have every tag on a separate line :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<ns1:HBA xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns1:TITLE>TEXT</ns1:TITLE>
<ns1:NAME>TEXT</ns1:NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, and I use this way to solve.

Try to use the "Namespace" defined in the `setPrefix`. Use the **"namespace"** instead of "**prefix**" as `startTag`'s first parametr.

Example:

```
serializer.setPrefix("ns1", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");
serializer.startTag("http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" , "HBA");
```

The output should be:

```
<ns1:HBA>
```

If you want to separate the tags, use `setFeature`.

```
setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
```

Reference:

- [XMLPULL V1 API Features](http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html)